# jquery href .indexOf, how to exclude

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I'm on www.forum.com, and, other than the homepage, the URL always has all kinds of additional text, for example, *www.forum.com/post1/oh-yeah* or *www.forum.com/post999/oh-baby* but I want to create an if statement that excludes everything other than www.forum.com, how do I do this?

In other words, how to do this:

```
if ( href.indexOf('forum.com') === 'forum.com' ){
    console.log('href value is exactly forum.com, with no additional string');
} else {
    console.log('href url contains more than just forum.com');
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke the `href.indexOf('forum.com')` The result is an integer. In a case you get `-1`, it is because it is non existent.

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a
>   specified value in a string.
>   This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.
>   For more [information](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

So instead of `(href.indexOf('forum.com') === 'forum.com')` you need to do `(href.indexOf('/') == -1)` which would mean that there is nothing after `www.forum.com`

```
if (href.indexOf('/') == -1) {
  console.log('href value is exactly forum.com, with no additional string');
} else {
  console.log('href url contains more than just forum.com');
}
```

This code snippet may help

```js
href = "www.forum.com/test-1";

if (href.indexOf('/') == -1) {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "href value is exactly forum.com, with no additional string";
} else {  
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "href url contains more than just forum.com";
}

href = "www.forum.com";

if (href.indexOf('/') == -1) {
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "href value is exactly forum.com, with no additional string";
} else {  
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "href url contains more than just forum.com";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="test">Test</p>

<p id="test1">Test</p>
```

Comment: oddly, this one didn't work for me, even though, it looks like it should. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answers you have here so far are all good. I just going to include something else you might want to consider.  If you are trying to grab the url and then look for anything after the hostname, you might want to simply check like this:

```
if(window.location.pathname != '' || window.location.search != ''){
    //stuff after the current url
}
```

`window.location.pathname` will handle both examples you provided.  If your url has query strings (things with `?` in them), then `window.location.search` will handle that.

Answer (score 0):

This will be another good solution.

```
 var href="www.forum.com";

 //ADDED href.indexOf("www.forum.com")==0 for extra verification

 if (href.match("www.forum.com$") && href.indexOf("www.forum.com")==0) {
     alert("ONLY URL");
 }
 else
 {
     alert("URL CONTAINS SOMETHING EXTRA");
 }
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/vypgLdtz/4/)**